# Custom class checkout submit button text for a specific payment method in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, hook, payment-gateway, hook-woocommerce

I need to make custom class the order_button_text for a specific payment gateway (bacs).

This my function:

```html
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways' );
function woocommerce_available_payment_gateways( $available_gateways ) {
    if (! is_checkout() ) return $available_gateways;  // stop doing anything if we're not on checkout page.
    if (array_key_exists('bacs',$available_gateways)) {
        // Gateway ID for Bacs is 'bacs'. 
         $available_gateways['bacs']->order_button_text = __( 'Order Pay', 'woocommerce' );
    }
    return $available_gateways;
}
```

I wont insert some custom class css (like font, color, etc..) in: ->order_button_text = __( 'Order Pay', 'woocommerce' );

---

I look a second function:

```html
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_button_html', 'misha_custom_button_html' );
 
function misha_custom_button_html( $button_html ) {
    $order_button_text = 'Submit';
        $button_html = '<button type="submit" class="button alt" name="woocommerce_checkout_place_order" id="place_order" value="' . esc_attr( $order_button_text ) . '" data-value="' . esc_attr( $order_button_text ) . '">' . esc_html( $order_button_text ) . '</button>';
}
```

I am trying to integrate this second function only in the case of the payment method (bacs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by `javascript`. you can check `payment_method` on the change of radio button.

> Get selected payment method using `:checked`.

```
var payment_method = $('input[name=payment_method]:checked').val();
```

> You can also check on page load which payment method is selected using
> the `updated_checkout` javascript trigger.

```
$( 'body' ).on( 'updated_checkout',function( data ){
    console.log( data );
} );
```

> Use the `change` event to get the selected payment method.

```
$(document).on( 'change', 'input[name="payment_method"]', function(){
    console.log( $(this).val() );
});
```

Check the below code. code goes in your active theme functions.php file.

```
function add_checkout_js(){
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function($){
            
            var payment_method = $('input[name=payment_method]:checked').val();
            
            ChnageButtonTextBasedOnPaymentMethod( payment_method );

            $( 'body' ).on( 'updated_checkout',function( data ){
                ChnageButtonTextBasedOnPaymentMethod( payment_method );
            } );
            
            $(document).on( 'change', 'input[name="payment_method"]', function(){
                ChnageButtonTextBasedOnPaymentMethod( $(this).val() );
            });

            function ChnageButtonTextBasedOnPaymentMethod( payment_method ){
                if( payment_method == 'bacs' ){
                    $('#place_order').addClass('custom-class');
                    $('#place_order').val('Order Pay');
                    $('#place_order').attr('data-value','Order Pay');
                    $('#place_order').html('Order Pay <img style="display: unset;" src="">');
                }else{
                    $('#place_order').removeClass('custom-class');
                    $('#place_order').val('Place order');
                    $('#place_order').attr('data-value','Place order');
                    $('#place_order').text('Place order');
                }
            }
            
        })(jQuery);
    </script>
    <?php
}

add_action( 'wp_footer', 'add_checkout_js', 10, 1 );
```

**Tested and works(Sorry for the low quality)**

[image]

Comment: Thanks mr. Bhautick, your formula works perfectly, it's really cool. Last little help, you can insert an image (svg,png,icon,etc..  - after $ ('# place_order'). text ('Pay with');

Comment: ----------

Something like this code:

    $( document.body ).on( 'payment_method_selected', function(){
        var selectedPaymentMethod = $( '.woocommerce-checkout input[name="payment_method"]:checked' ).attr( 'id' );
        $( '#place_order' ).find('.payment-icon');
        $( '#place_order' ).prepend('<span class="payment-icon '+ selectedPaymentMethod +'"></span>'); // or any element like from font-awesome.
    });
    $( document.body ).trigger( 'payment_method_selected' ); // this will trigger on page load, act as initialize the icon.
Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: are you using font-awesome?

Comment: I added an image tag you can now add your image source in there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231424/discussion-between-dom-and-bhautik).